# highcharts-export-clientside Unsupported export format

Tags: angularjs, pdf, highcharts

I'm using highcharts-ng, trying to do client side pdf download and keep getting Unsupported export format on this platform: application/pdf. If I use the highcharts server to generate the pdf it works fine.

```
options: {
  exporting: {
    type: 'application/pdf'
  }
},
func: function() {
    // button handler
    $('#vehicle-conversion-pdf-btn').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#vehicle-conversion').highcharts();
        chart.exportChart();
    });
}
```

I'm also loading the plugin last.

Comment: Need more info. What are you using to do the export? What plugin are you loading last? Have you tried not loading it last? Etc

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem almost like this. 
I had been imported "highcharts-export-clientside.js" to my web page, but it didn't work. (from [this documentation](http://a----.github.io/highcharts-export-clientside)  )

my problem fixed with this line :

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
```

Altogether you must have this imports in your html file :

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
```